# IME: How to enter katakana rather than hiragana with Swype keyboard

Tags: languages, swype

I am using the [Swype Japanese keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.swype.trial) for Android. With the Japanese language selected, how do I tell my keyboard to enter katakana instead of hiragana?

Thanks.